# Recursion issue?

Tags: java, recursion

So this is my first recursion function (I hope!) and I'm unsure why it isn't working, (aka red lines) any ideas?

```
int myFactorial(int C) { //underlined, expects ";"

    int n = Integer.parseInt(objectsChooseField.getText());
    int r = Integer.parseInt(chooseFromField.getText());

    if (C == 1){
        return 1; //underlined, cannot return value from method whose result type is void
    }
    return (C*(myFactorial(n/(r(n-r))))); //underlined
}
```

Comment: whar are you trying to achieve? factorial or combination?

Comment: Whatever it is that you are trying to do you should read from the GUI in _another_ function rather than with each iteration.

Comment: @BoristheSpider What GUI?

Comment: For each "underlined" there is a specific error message. This is what you need to report.

Comment: @Ingo I am making an assumption that variables called things like `objectsChooseField` with `getText()` methods are part of a GUI.

Comment: From the errors it looks a lot like you are trying to nest a method in another method. You cannot do this in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So you have the ActionPerformed method. Put in the code like:

```
private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(objectsChooseField.getText());
    int r = Integer.parseInt(chooseFromField.getText());
    int result = faculty( n ) / ( faculty( r ) * ( n - r ));
    //--- Output result to somewhere
}
```

And the faculty computation method itself:

```
/** Computes the faculty of n */
public int faculty( n ) {
  if ( n > 1 )
    return n * faculty( n - 1 );
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Well thank you so much! You're definitely my hero at this given moment! :)

Answer (score 10):

Here: `r(n-r)`.

`r` is not a function, but an local variable `int`.

Do you mean `r * (n - r)`?

Comment: Originally this is the equation I'm to use: C(n,r) = n!/(r!(n-r)) However I realized "!" isn't a valid operator in java, but I figured I'll deal with it later.

Comment: You'll have to write your own method to calculate the factorial.

Comment: @Boris the Spider - or not - [relevant link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/05/08/10416823.aspx), found on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1dz2gg/mathematical_formulas_are_designed_to_be_pretty/)

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't the recusive statement be:

```
return ( C * myFactorial ( C - 1 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your equation does not state any recursion. The faculty could by computed with recursion.

```
public int MyMethod() {
int n = Integer.parseInt(objectsChooseField.getText());
int r = Integer.parseInt(chooseFromField.getText());
int result = C( n, r );
}

public int C( int n, int r ) {
  int res = faculty( n ) / ( faculty( r ) * ( n - r ));
  return res;
}

//--- Computing the faculty itself could be done by recursion :-)
public int faculty( n ) {
  if ( n > 1 )
    return n * faculty( n - 1 );
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is great, however how could I place it under an actionPerformed button without 'redding' out all of my code?

Comment: Put the lines from "MyMethod" into your actionPerformed() method. You could even integrate the line from C() into that one. So the only method remaining outside actionPerformed is the computation of the faculty.

Comment: right, so what if it will not allow me to edit the actionPerformed line...?

Comment: How does the line look like? Could you please post it here.

Comment: private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {